# Sencha Touch & Cordova: Overriding AppDelegate.m

Tags: sencha-touch-2, cordova-3

I'm using Touch 2.3.0, Cmd 4.0.1.45, and Cordova 3.1.0 to build a native iOS application. I'll be testing the application with self-signed certificates, so as I understand it I need to add the following code to AppDelegate.m to bypass the SSL cert validation:

```
    @implementation NSURLRequest(DataController)
    + (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host
    {
        return YES;
    }
    @end
```

I've generated a test application with `sencha generate app TestApp`, then added the Cordova support with `sencha cordova init`. I get the expected "cordova" directory tree in my project folder, but I'm not seeing `classes/AppDelegate.m`. Am I generating my project correctly, or do I need to add my own AppDelegate.m file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I was just ahead of the process, which should look like the following:

1. Create your project: `sencha generate app MyApp`
2. Add Cordova support: `sencha cordova init com.example.MyApp MyApp`
3. And here's the essential step I was missing: `sencha app build native`

During step 3, you should see the following logging:

```
[INF] -cordova-platform-add:
[INF]    [script] Cordova: Missing platforms ios. Attempting add.
[INF] [shellscript] Downloading cordova library for ios...
[INF] [shellscript] Download complete
[INF] [shellscript] Checking iOS requirements...
[INF] [shellscript] Creating ios project...
[INF] [shellscript] Preparing ios project
```

At this point, Cmd adds an XCode project to your app in `cordova/platforms/ios`. You can then customize the `AppDelegate.m` (found in that project) and run another build to pick up those changes.